# How to override a value in i18n translation?

Tags: jhipster

I want to override certain values in translation without having to duplicate an entire json file.

The way we work is that we do not touch the code generate by JHipster. So for example, our `en/global.json` file looks like:

```
{
    "global": {
        "title": "Sponsor",
        "menu": {
            "home": "Home",
            "entities": {
                "main": "Entities",
                "tenantSponsor": "Tenant",
                "eventSponsor": "Event",
                "eventDefinitionSponsor": "Event Definition",
                "venueSponsor": "Venue",
```

Now, let's say I only want to change the value for `venueSponsor`. I can change it in the `en/global.json` file, but I'm looking for another solution. I would like to be able to create a seperate file (eg `en/global_override.json`) and override only what interests me:

```
{
    "global": {
        "menu": {
            "entities": {
                "venueSponsor": "My overriden Venue",
```

I couldn't find any solution.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: I doubt you could do it without impacting webpack configuration but it should be a minor impact by using JSON concat. maybe using https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-jsons-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar. We use deepmerge to handle the merging of configs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge

Code looks like:

`const fullConfig = deepmerge.all([
  baseConfig,
  overrideConfig,
]);`